# ForEach Identifiable Struct Object Properties Into List Ordered By categoryName

Tags: struct, foreach, swiftui

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I've been stuck on this for a couple of days and just can't seem to find the answer.

1.) I'm using a separate swift file with an Identifiable Struct that has an object with 2 of the Struct properties, *name* & *categoryName*. (side note, I'm using *var* instead of *let* in the object because the rows can't be rearranged with the .onMove modifier as a constant)

```
    //STRUCT

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var categoryName: String
}



//OBJECT

var items : [Item] = [

    //CLOTHING
    Item(name: "Hats", categoryName: "Clothing"),
    Item(name: "Shirts", categoryName: "Clothing"),
    Item(name: "Pants", categoryName: "Clothing"),

    //Electronics
    Item(name: "Macbook", categoryName: "Electronics"),
    Item(name: "Macbook Adapter", categoryName: "Electronics"),
    Item(name: "iPhone", categoryName: "Electronics"),


]
```

2.) In a swiftui file I have this code to build the list, using a nested ForEach loop to pull the categoryName, add it to the Section header, then another to loop out the items.

```
    //List code

 NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { currentItem in
                    Section(header: Text(currentItem.categoryName)){
                        ForEach(items) { currentItem in
                             NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetail(itemData: currentItem)){ ItemRow(item: currentItem)

                            }
                        }
```

---

Unfortunately what I get is a laughable result.

[image]

I get my categoryName in the section header and I get my items listed below it. Actually, I get ALL of the items listed below it, regardless of category. Then in a very confusing fashion the sections will print out exactly as many times as the rows in my object array.

In this instance I have 6, so I get 6 rows. Yet, of the 2 categoryName strings "Clothing" and "Electronics", they'll print out 3 times each.

It feels like there's a simple way to do "for each categoryName in items.categoryName add a title to the section and list the corresponding name" - but I'm not cracking this one.

Hoping someone here can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have flat array and just iterate though it several times, so result is also flat multiplied several times.

Ok, for model you selected, ie `items`, the result you tried to accomplish can be reached with the following...

```
List {
    ForEach(Array(Set(items.compactMap{ $0[keyPath: \.categoryName] })), id: \.self) { category in
        Section(header: Text(category)) {
            ForEach(items.filter { $0.categoryName == category }) { currentItem in
                 NavigationLink(destination: Text("ItemDetail(itemData: currentItem)")){ Text("\(currentItem.name)") }
                }
            }
        }
}
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

However I would select different model for `items`, ie. dictionary as `[categoryName: Item]`

Comment: I want to point out that both answers from Asperi and @Mojtaba work. The key difference is that Asperi's code used List rows correctly for each item (item contains within an individual row), whereas Mojtaba's code below, even after a bit of modification for errors didn't have the same structure. 

I want to thank you both for the explanations and help on this! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your array by category:

```
let sections = Dictionary(grouping: items) { $0.categoryName }
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var keys: [String] = { sections.map {$0.key} }

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(keys, id: \.self) { section in
            Section(header: Text(section)){
                ForEach(self.sections[section] ?? []) { currentItem in
                    Text(currentItem.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that I have simplified your code to run on my machine but changes are not effecting the answer</sub>